# Is it possible to add an SVN repo as apt-get update?

Tags: apt, svn

The title already says most of it. I wanted to know if it's possible to handle `svn update` commands over `apt-get upgrade`. Basically, every time when a specific SVN repo is outdated, I should get the update notification, like with any other package.

Is a configuration like that at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Is too difficult to be desirable. Only package maintainer develop scripts to do this.